# Correlating assignees with authors in SonarQube

Tags: code-review, sonarqube, code-quality

I'm aware that **assignees** are the effective SonarQube uses that I've created on the platform, but **authors** come from SCM commit data. The question I need to solve comes from the fact that I'm seeing several *strange* authors in the list, even some with computer (user@myComputer) names in them, which don't seem to resemble actual SCM users/credentials.

Questions:

1. Where does **author** data actually comes from?
2. How can I see actual correlation data for SonarQube **assignees** vs **authors**
3. Is there some way to force non-automatically assigned issues to someone with extra rules or alike?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here are your answers :

1. Author is coming from the SCM data. According to your "strange" authors, I suspect you are using git and anyone can configure his account with any name (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)
2. In order to correlate the assignees (SonarQube user) and the author (SCM account), as an administrator you can add SCM accounts in `Administration > Security > Users` :
   [image: SCM Accounts]
3. You can set a default assignee when there is no match with current assignees in `Administration > Configuration > General` :
   [image: Default assignee]

Comment: Superb answer, we've already checked our Eclipse configs for #1 and there were some "anomalies" indeed ;)

Comment: #2 will definitely take some more time and, I guess we won't be using #3. Thanks a lot!